# Pointer to member type incompatible with object type when calling a pointer to a member of a derived class

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class, pointer-to-member

I have defined a class template such as this one:

```
template <const category_id_t category, class Base>
class Node : public Base
{
...
    template <typename Derived, class T>
    void on_message( const frame_t& frame, void (Derived::*call)(const T*) )
    {
        if ( frame.length == sizeof(T) )
            (this->*(call))((T*)frame.data);
    }
}
```

The argument `category` serves as a token to implement several similar classes and provide proper specialization according to specific categories. The above class is then derived like this:

```
template <class Base>
class Sys : public Node<CID_SYS, Base>
{
    Sys() : Node<CID_SYS, Base>() { /* ... */ }
    ....
};
```

Class `Sys` is only a class that provides an base interface to objects of category `CID_SYS` (enum, value = 5) and serves as a base class to the actual implementation of the interface:

```
class SysImpl : public Sys<CAN>
{
    ...
    /* Parse remote notifications */
    void on_notify( const state_info_t* ) { /* ... */ }
};

SysImpl sys;
```

Finally I have a function that calls the base class `Node<CID_SYS, Base>` member function `on_message()` like this:

```
void foo(const frame_t& frame)
{ sys.on_message(frame, &SysImpl::on_notify ); }
```

The compiler throws an error around the line `(this->*(call))((T*)frame.data)` saying

> error: pointer to member type 'void (SysImpl::)(const state_info_t*)' is incompatible with object type 'Node<(category_id_t)5u, CAN>'

The compiler has successfully guessed what template function to call, it's just that it doesn't seem to "recognize" that `this` is from a derived class.

What I'd like is to call any member function of a class derived from `Node<CID_SYS, CAN>`, not only stand-alone functions (which works perfectly well so far, not shown in the excerpt above).

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried to `static_cast` `this` to appropriate type?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at how many of the [standard library alhorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) handle things like predicated and callbacks, using templates. I also suggest you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: As for your error, in the `on_message` function `this` is not a pointer to an `SysImpl` object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think OP uses CRTP so it can be actually pointer to `SysImpl`

Comment: @W.F. Thanks! That did it! I'm a bit rusty with templates and all that jazz, I guess but that worked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't use the standard template library in fact and that is intentional as the program shall run on AVR (Atmel microcontroller). Size matters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude true of course, but it's easy as cast to make it `SysImpl *`. We are sure that `this` can be treated as `SysImpl *` because of used CRTP...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `on_message` function the variable `this` is not a pointer to `SysImpl`, it's type is `Node<CID_SYS, CAN>*`. The `Node` template class have no member `on_notify` so you can't call it on an instance of `Node`. It must be called on an instance of `Derived` (which should be `SysImpl`).

That's why you get the error and need to cast `this` to `Derived*`:

```
(static_cast<Derived*>(this)->*(call))(...);
```

Of course, this only works if `Derived` actually *is* derived from the `Node` class.

Comment: we could perform `static_assert` to check if `Derived` is same as `Base`